# Why is this function an affine function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

Why is the following function an affine function?
$$f(x)=(P^{1/2}x,c^\top x)$$
I learnt that affine functions have the pattern like $f(x)=Ax+b$, is there any relation between the two function?

Maybe I got it.

Suppose $A = (P^{1/2},c^\top)^\top$, $A(x,0)^\top=(P^{1/2}x,c^\top x)$

So $f(x)=(P^{1/2}x,c^\top x)=A(x,0)^\top$ conforms to the pattern of affine function.

Is that right?

Comment: What are $P$ and $c$?

Comment: @Servaes Some certain matrices.

Comment: Then what does $P^{1/2}$ mean?

Comment: @Servaes It means $\sqrt{P}$, but never mind, $P^{1/2}$ is just a certain matrice here.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would take the square root of a matrix, but I'll just assume its some matrix then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition:** A function $g:\ R^n\ \longrightarrow\ R^m$ is *affine* if it is of the form $$g(x)=Mx+v$$ 
for some matrix $M\in\operatorname{Mat}(n\times m,R)$ and vector $v\in R^m$.

---

Given a pair of matrices $A,B\in\operatorname{Mat}(n\times n,R)$, the function
$$f:\ R^n\ \longrightarrow\ R^{2n}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ (Ax,Bx),$$
satisfies $f(x)=Cx$ for all $x\in R^n$, where $C\in\operatorname{Mat}(n\times2n,R)$ is given by
$$C:=\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence $f$ is indeed an affine function, with $M=C$ and $v=0$ in the definition above.